# How can I select specific words from a webpage by keyboard command on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04

Suppose we got a passage on a web page:

Traditionally, keyboard shortcuts are written like so: Alt + F1. This means that you should press the Alt and F1 keys simultaneously. This is normally best achieved by holding down the modifier key (such as Ctrl or Alt or the Super(windows logo) key) and then pressing the second key once. You can then release the modifier key.

Now we want to select from that passage: Traditionally written : Alt + F1

Now we cant use shift+arrow because that select continuous words or letters. But then how can I select the words in the particular fashion.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 version

Comment: use control and "F" key to search for the word. Where it will search and highlight the information

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the selection of specific words is possible in Firefox but not possible in Chromium and Chrome.

In Firefox, you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then use your mouse to select the words you want.

Comment: Suppose You don't have a mouse. How can you do the work now?

Comment: Then I would download the webpage and then use my favorite text editor to open its HTML and select multiple words using just the keyboard.

Comment: can't we do the selection thing on a live webpage?

Comment: You can't without a mouse because there is no caret/cursor to speak of on a live webpage.

Answer (score 0):

In [**Chromium**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/chromium-browser/) we can find any word with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, below shown for `words`. Pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> will proceed to the next entry found:

[image]

On pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> the highlighted word will be selected. Extending the selection word by word can be done by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RightArrow</kbd>.

[image]

No mouse involved.

Comment: Can we select more than one separate words by that way?

Comment: U just discussed how to find out a particular word. But Suppose now u have more than one particular words. Then what will u do?

Comment: @AmirKhasru: you can only select coherent text by this.